# I'm creating a PDF file on a server using Microsoft Word.  How do I get Word to close?

Tags: php, apache, function

I wrote a function in PHP to convert `doc` to `pdf`, but it doesn't work.
In the beginning, my function worked, although it didn't close `Winword.exe`, I closed it by hand.

Now, when I open the site page with this function, Apache stops working.

```
$word = new COM('word.application');
$word->Visible = 0;
$word->Documents->Open('C:\Apache\smena3.krw.rzd\www\docnz\oblachnye.docx');
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs(APPLICATION_DOCNZ_FOLDER.'\oblachnye.pdf',17);
$word->Quit('0','0','0');
$word = null;
$this->render('docnz');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was already working and the only problem is that apache stops working, you could consider adding to your script a command to restart apache.

I don't know what kind of a system you are running, but this might work if you're running linux:

```
$restart = shell_exec('apachectl restart');
echo $restart;
```

The last echo would be just to make sure apache restarted correctly.

Comment: there is now not only hangs apache, but also a function only opens the Word, but does not create a pdf.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you are trying to say. I guess apache is still not working for you, you mentioned before there was a version of your script that was working but that wasn't closing down word. Could you post that version? It might give me a better idea of what your problem is. You could try using something like this to close word down after running the script: fclose('C:\Apache\smena3.krw.rzd\www\docnz\oblachnye.docx');

Comment: First: funtion working - word no closed. Now: funtion not working - word open and no closed and apache stop working. And the strangest thing I have not changed the function

Comment: That does certainly sound weird, chances are you installed updates and that's what is affecting the script, that's the only thing I can think of anyway, you might want to check this link out though: http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/02/06/convert-doc-to-pdf-in-php/ you'd have to start your function from scratch though